# Does pthread_detach free up the stack allocated to the child thread, after the child thread as exited

Tags: pthreads, posix

I have used pthread_detach inorder to free up the stack allocated to the child thread, but this is not working, I guess it does not free up the memory.....

I don't want to use pthread_join. I know join assures me of freeing up the stack for child, but, I don't want the parent to hang up until the child thread terminates, I want my parent to do some other work in the mean time. So, I have used detach, as it will not block the parent thread.

Please, help me. I have been stuck..

Comment: How do you know pthread_detach doesn't free the memory ? Show some code.

Comment: 13 questions, none accepted, never voted. Please put something back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is not working

Yes it *is*. You are likely mis-interpreting your observations.

> I want my parent to do some other work in the mean time

That's usually the reason to create threads in the first place, and you *can* do that:

```
pthread_create(...);
do_some_work();     // both current and new threads work in parallel
pthread_join(...);  // wait for both threads to finish
report_results();
```

> I don't want to use pthread_join. I know join assures me of freeing up the stack for child

Above statement is false: it assures no such thing. A common implementation will cache the now available child stack for reuse (in case you'll create another thread shortly).

Answer (score 1):

YES - according to http://cursuri.cs.pub.ro/~apc/2003/resources/pthreads/uguide/users-16.htm it frees memory either when the thread ends or immediately if the thread has already ended...

As you don't provide any clue as how you determine that the memory is not freed up I can only assume that the method you use to determine it is not sufficient...

Comment: The word 'free' does not appear in the document you cited, and free is different from 'reclaim'.